# Spring: parse url to get filter

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

There is a way using Spring having some code like this:

```
@RequestMapping("/animals/view/*")
public ModelAndView view(@SomeKindOfAnnotation AnimalFilter filter) {
    return new ModelAndView("myViewPage", "animals", animalService.filterBy(filter));
}
```

I want call urls like these:

- `<myContextPath>/animals/view/` (extracts all animals)
- `<myContextPath>/animals/view/type/cat` (extracts only cats)
- `<myContextPath>/animals/view/type/cat/color/yellow` (extracts only brown cats)
- `<myContextPath>/animals/view/type/insect/legs/6` (extracts only insects with 6 legs)

and having the object animalFilter already filled with the data contained into the url.

AnimalFilter is a simple POJO class with getter and setter for every type of fields that the user can use for filter animals.

If there isn't a way doing this is possible to create the new annotation `@SomeKindOfAnnotation` for filling the `AnimalFilter` automatically?

Answer (score 1):

What you can do is build a PropertyEditor or you can use a object mapper like Jackson if you are using json value, but if you really want to use a annotation you can use AOP:

Examples using AOP:

```
@Before(value="@annotation(audit) && args(.......)")
public void beforeHandler(SomeKindOfAnnotation audit, .......) {
```

Example using PropertiesEditor:

```
public class SomeKindOfPropertie extends PropertiesEditor {

@Override
public void setAsText(String text) throws IllegalArgumentException {
    // Reminding all parameters in the request are String.
            .......
            setValue(new SomeKind(text));
} 

}
```

In your controller you need to register the propertiesEditor on the binder:

```
@InitBinder("filter")
public void initBinder(WebDataBinder binder) {
    binder.registerCustomEditor(SomeKind.class, new SomeKindOfPropertie());
}
```

More Information: 
http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.2.x/spring-framework-reference/html/validation.html

Comment: With the `PropertiesEditor` can I parse the url to fill my class `AnimalFilter`?

Comment: Yes, you can do what you want, you will receive a String parameter with the value of the request.